# Padding removed from email signature

Tags: email, html-table, html-email

I've tried creating an email signature but whenever I paste it into outlook the padding for the bottom of the logo gets removed? I also tried adding margin instead but it still got deleted? The only way is to add a space in manually after, but I'm sure this is not a good practice?

Thanks

```
<div>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation" style="font-size: 0px;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="vertical-align: top;"><div style="margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; border-radius: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                        <img src="https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mysigmail/upload/2019-04-29-hzc85zi6onw.png" alt="avatar" style="width: 150px; border-radius: 0px;">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the padding to the parent `td` cell instead of the `div`

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
    ** content **
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As a heads up:

- Outlook 2013-2019 do not work with `padding-top`
- apply the image width to the image. Outlook will ignore the width in style
- `border-radius` does not work with Outlook

Good luck.